# Referencing to an object property

Tags: php, oop, properties, reference

Is it possible to create a variable that references to its own object property?

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    public $num_of_call=array();

    public function call($number)
    {
     if(!isset($this->num_of_call[$number]))
     {
         $this->num_of_call[$number] = 1;
         return;
     }
     $counter &= $this->num_of_call[$number];
     $counter++;
    }
}
```

I test it but, but it yields an error 'Undefined variable $counter'
And, if I remove the ampersand, it turns out that it's not a reference since the property `num_of_call` is still zero.
Is there a way to create an 'alias' (reference) to the object property?
Because, this problem arises when the object property has long name and it's an array, and I want to catch it in the variable caching (if it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

`$var &= $value` -- it is shorthand for `$var = $var & $value`.

You need do this:

```
 $counter = &$this->num_of_call[$number];
```